# go AzureAD invalid operation: cannot indirect app.GetPasswordCredentials() (value of type []models.PasswordCredentialable)

Tags: azure, go, azure-sdk

I would like to read all App Registration with passwords and certificates.

I can get the App Registration names with this code `*app.GetDisplayName()`, but when I try to run `*app.GetPasswordCredentials()` I get the compiler error

invalid operation: cannot indirect app.GetPasswordCredentials() (value of type []models.PasswordCredentialable)

Does someone know how to fix that?

Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    msgraphcore "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go-core"
    "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/models"
    "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/models/odataerrors"

    azidentity "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    msgraphsdk "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go"
)

var (
    clientSecret = "XXX"
    clientID     = "XXX"
    tenantID     = "XXX"
)

func main() {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(tenantID, clientID, clientSecret, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to create credential: %v\n", err)
    }

    // create a graph service client
    client, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClientWithCredentials(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating client: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // get all users
    resultUsers, err := client.Users().Get(context.Background(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error getting users: %v\n", err)
    }

    restultApps, err := client.Applications().Get(context.Background(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error getting apps: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(restultApps)

    // User PageIterator to iterate through all apps
    pageIteratorApps, err := msgraphcore.NewPageIterator[models.Applicationable](restultApps, client.GetAdapter(), models.CreateApplicationCollectionResponseFromDiscriminatorValue)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating page iterator: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    err = pageIteratorApps.Iterate(context.Background(), func(app models.Applicationable) bool {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", *app.GetDisplayName(), *app.GetAppId(), *app.GetPasswordCredentials())
        return true
    })

    // Use PageIterator to iterate through all users
    pageIterator, err := msgraphcore.NewPageIterator[models.Userable](resultUsers, client.GetAdapter(), models.CreateUserCollectionResponseFromDiscriminatorValue)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating page iterator: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    err = pageIterator.Iterate(context.Background(), func(user models.Userable) bool {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", *user.GetDisplayName(), *user.GetMail())
        return true
    })
}
```

I tried to find an answer on Google, but did not have any luck.

Comment: A slice needs to be indexec, not dereferenced: `pp.GetPasswordCredentials()[0]`. Take the Tour of Go and try to read error messages carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. You get back a list of passwords and have to iterate over them oder access a single one with the index.